# Unable to run simple appium program - Original error: Permission to start activity denied

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, appium, android-testing

I am not able to run a simple appium program. When I was trying to run it throws an error message - A new session could not be created. (`Original error: Permission to start activity denied.`). I googled and in some blogs it was mentioned that we should use `AndroidManifest.xml` file and add an activity exported:true. What is `AndroidManifest` and why should we use it?

Can someone provide the actual `AndroidManifest.XML` file which is useful for mobile automation(APPIUM)?

Here is the stack trace:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Permission to start activity denied.) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 9.98 seconds
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'
System info: host: 'Santosh', ip: '192.168.1.11', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_31'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
```

Comment: Can you post some code so we can see what have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem. I got it solved by not changing anything in the Manifest file.

**There are two things to check:**

**1.** It seems that you are trying to start an activity which may not be the start activity. Check which is the start activity by looking into the Android manifest file intent-filter. Start the activity which has the intent filter `android.intent.action.MAIN`.

I prefer NOT to mention the start activity explicitly in the appium test java file using capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "your activity");  unless needed by your test logic.

**2.** I prefer using RemoteWebDriver than AndroidDriver. Thats my preference though